# Combining data in two projections?

Tags: raster, gdal, coordinate-system, united-states

The [PAMAP](http://www.dcnr.state.pa.us/topogeo/pamap/) dataset comes divided between two different projections: Pennsylvania North State Plane and Pennsylvania South State Plane.

I'd like a great big DEM of the whole state of Pennsylvania. `gdal_merge.py` can help me make this happen, but I'm going to need to reproject at least one half of the dataset first.

Is there a standard way of choosing how to do such a reprojection? Should I map everything to the North or South Plane or, perhaps, construct an intermediate projection and map everything to that?

Answer (score 2):

Converting one State Plane to the adjacent system is always on the safe side, unless you need sub-meter accuracy.

Alternatively, you can use `EPSG:102004 USA_Contiguous_Lambert_Conformal_Conic`

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=33 +lat_2=45 +lat_0=39 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs
```

which is valid for the most of the United States.